# On Screen Keypad in application C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to Create  KEYPAD for my application for a touch screen computer, I can't use windows onscreen keyboard. in my application in Form I have my KEYPAD GROUPBOX and I have multiple textbox's and one datagridview.

I did try to use SendKeys.Send() by this code

[image]

for code :

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    const int W_ACTIVATE = 0x08000000;

    public Form1()
    {      
      InitializeComponent();      
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
      get
      {
        CreateParams param = base.CreateParams;
        param.ExStyle |= W_ACTIVATE;
        return param;
      }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     Button btn = (Button)sender;
        string btnTag = btn.Tag.ToString();
        switch (btnTag)
        {
            case "0":
                SendKeys.Send("(0)");

                break;
            case "1":
                SendKeys.Send("(1)");
                break;
            case "2":
                SendKeys.Send("(2)");
                break;
            case "3":
                SendKeys.Send("(3)");
                break;
            case "4":
                SendKeys.Send("(4)");
                break;
            case "5":
                SendKeys.Send("(5)");
                break;
            case "6":
                SendKeys.Send("(6)");
                break;
            case "7":
                SendKeys.Send("(7)");
                break;
            case "8":
                SendKeys.Send("(8)");
                break;
            case "9":
                SendKeys.Send("(9)");
                break;

            default:
                // Do Something
                break;
        }
    }
  }
```

But it doesn't work,I need Help ,I would like to know how to make the keys type into the textbox and active cell in Datagridview which is focused.

Comment: you can just set the TextBox's Text property, no need to use sendkey to simulate keystrokes.

Comment: Ok And How can I find which control is active [textbox], Datagridview [cell , row], ... ????

Comment: Have you tried: SendKeys.Send("0", True);

Comment: Well, either you can loop through every control (and every children of every control, and so forth) and check for the "IsFocused" property, or you can google to see if maybe there's a "Form.FocusedControl" property or something you can get it from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't expect `SendKeys` to work: Your application has `Focus`, but none of your input controls has - the `Button` you just pressed has.

Here is a way to do it:

```
// the current input control
Control focusedCtl = null;

// variables to keep track of the cursor in the dgv cells
int curSelStart = 0;
TextBox curTB = null;


// this is the common Enter event for all our input controls
// we store which was entered/focused last
private void control_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    focusedCtl = sender as Control;
}

// this is the common Click event for all buttons in your keypad
private void padButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // reference to the sender
    Button padKey = sender as Button;

    // one way to get the text to process, Tag would be another
    string input = padKey.Text;

    // we do a lot of checks and beep&leave on fail
    if (focusedCtl == null) { Console.Beep(); return ;}

    // try to decide which is the receiving control
    DataGridView dgv = focusedCtl as DataGridView;
    TextBox tb = focusedCtl as TextBox;

    if (dgv != null)
    {
        DataGridViewCell cell = dgv.CurrentCell;
        if (cell == null) { Console.Beep(); return; }
        else
        {
            if (curTB == null) curSelStart = -1; 
            else curSelStart = curTB.SelectionStart;

            if (input == "C") cell.Value = cell.Value == null ? 
                              "" : TrimLast( cell.Value.ToString());
            else
            {
                string cs = cell.Value == null ? "" : cell.Value.ToString();

                if (curSelStart >= 0 && curSelStart < cs.Length) 
                     cell.Value = cs.Insert(curSelStart, input);
                else cell.Value = cs + input;
            }
        }
    }
    else  if (tb != null)
    {
        if (input == "C") tb.Text = TrimLast(tb.Text);
        else
        {
            int sstart = tb.SelectionStart;
            tb.Text = tb.Text.Insert(sstart, input);
            tb.SelectionStart += input.Length;
        }
    }

    else Console.Beep();
}

string TrimLast(string s) { return s.Substring(0, Math.Max(0, s.Length - 1)); }

// we need a reference to the Textbox that is used for editing
private void dataGridView1_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.EditType == typeof(DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl))
    {
        dataGridView1.BeginEdit(false);
        curTB = (TextBox)dataGridView1.EditingControl;
        if (curTB == null) return; 
        else curSelStart = curTB.SelectionStart;
        dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);
    }
}
```

Getting the correct cursor position in the DGV cell is not as simple as with a TextBox..It takes an extra event and two helper variables.

Comment: Thanks for your Help mate ,,,,  I just add focusedCtl = sender as Control; to dataGridView1_CellEnter  and every thing work perfect and one small bug when we input more than 3 digit last digit go's to one before in end ...